# Java Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to understand Inheritance a little better but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm creating a base object for a pizza. A base, deep pan or thin. I have 2 classes, Pizza, PizzaBase. I'm keeping the private variables in Pizza, and trying to call them when building my pizzabase. Here's my 2 classes. But its not working. I get the message setCost(double) is undefined for the type Pizza

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Sorry. It's not working. I'm getting the message, setCost(double) is undefined for the type Pizza

Comment: Well it (setCost(double)...) is properly defined, actually. Are you sure the code you posted is the same as what you have on your screen? Also your use of inheritance is a little weird. Perhaps you could use `composition` over `inheritance` for Pizza and PizzaBase?

Comment: Why do you create instance of the pizzaBase in pizzabase ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code is wrong in every way.

Listen to the compiler: if it says you can't call `setCost()` on `Pizza` because there is no such method, it means you didn't define it.

You ought to do something more like this:

```
public class Pizza {
    private double cost; // double is NOT a good idea for money

    public Pizza(double cost) { 
        if (cost < 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("we won't pay you to take our pizza!");
        this.cost = cost; 
    }

    public double getCost() { return this.cost; }
}

public class ThinPizza extends Pizza {
    private static final double DEFAULT_COST = 2.0;

    public ThinPizza() { this(DEFAULT_COST); }
    public ThinPizza(double cost) { super(cost); }
}

public class ThickPizza extends Pizza {
    private static final double DEFAULT_COST = 5.0;

    public ThickPizza() { this(DEFAULT_COST); }
    public ThickPizza(double cost) { super(cost); }
}
```

You can call `getCost()` on thin and thick pizza, because it IS-A `Pizza`.

Comment: Nice. Love the IAE, haha!

Comment: Thanks - it's a valid check, don't you agree?  Why make a value object ignorant when it can be smart?

Comment: True :) p.s, `return this.cost;` - why `this.`?

Comment: I see this on OP's code: `public void setCost( double cost ){
    this.cost = cost;
}` You are saying that this doesn't constitute the definition of a `setCost` method?

Comment: Matter of taste and choice.  Not necessary in getter context, but it makes clear that it's returning the member instance.

Comment: @Marko, either I missed it or it was edited in.  I don't believe it was there when I posted the answer.  The OP commented about the compiler error, which is why I amended my answer.

Comment: At the time you *posted* the answer, it was definitely there. It could be that you didn't look at the updated answer, or notice the difference.

Comment: Could have been.  Sometimes I go too fast.  James posted this 19 minutes ago: "Sorry. It's not working. I'm getting the message, setCost(double) is undefined for the type Pizza".  My answer came 15 minutes ago.  Sounds like it wasn't there, but I'm still not certain.  vikingsteve says it was there, so you must be right.  I reacted to the comment, not the code.